# How safe is std::reduce for floating point?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++17

This example code is taken from cppreference for [`std::reduce`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <execution_policy>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v(10'000'007, 0.5);

    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double result = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << std::fixed << "std::accumulate result " << result
                  << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }

    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double result = std::reduce(std::par, v.begin(), v.end());
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "std::reduce result "
                  << result << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }
}
```

For those not familiar, `std::reduce` is similar to `std::accumulate` except:

> the elements of the range may be grouped and rearranged in arbitrary
>   order

[`std::par`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) means:

> Any such invocations executing in the same thread are indeterminately
>   sequenced with respect to each other.

Further the page for `std::reduce` says:

> The behavior is non-deterministic if binary_op is not associative or
>   not commutative.

The example output given is:

```
std::accumulate result 5000003.50000 took 12.7365 ms
std::reduce result 5000003.50000 took 5.06423 ms
```

AFAIK, neither Clang or GCC implement the Library TS's, so the sample is probably made up, but that's not the point of the question.

Given the properties of floating point, is this code "safe"? Would `std::reduce` actually produce the exact same result as `std::accumulate` or even through multiple tests?

<sub>The assumption here is the operation is purely addition, not multiplication.</sub>

Comment: It's safe as one result isn't any more correct than any other.   But that's different than being the same as accumulate -- which isn't going to give you the "correct" result necessarily, either.  So it's not really clear what you're asking.  What are you planning on doing with this information?

Comment: It isn't totally made up: I used the HPX implementation and then changed headers/namespaces to C++17

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately the quoted example is cooked up in order to produce exact result in floating point arithmetics, therefore does not really give any information on the numerical accuracy. If I understand std::reduce correctly, it should be more accurate than std::accumulate as it performs summation in a hierarchical fashion (it partitions the array, computes the sums of partitions, and proceeds recursively). But some further experimentation and better documentation is very much needed.

Answer (score 4):

When applied to floating point types, `std::plus` is not associative. `(a + b) + c` could be different from `a + (b + c)`

Given that, I would say the answer to your question

> Would `std::reduce` actually produce the exact same result as `std::accumulate` or even through multiple tests?

is:

It is possible for the results to be different. They could be same but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Do you think of the edge cases or of rounding errors if you say they "could be different``?

Answer (score 2):

An IEEE `double` has 53 significant bits, which is about 1E16 or so.

`10'000'007` has 10 digits.

This means that an IEEE `double` can *perfectly* represent every value from 0 to `10'000'007/2` at a step size of `0.5`.

`double` addition is deterministic, except often you can end up with "logical" values that are not representable as `double`, at which point rounding occurs.  As no sub sequence of adding those `10'000'007` elements can result in a number that `double` cannot perfectly represent, the result is deterministic and known.

Doing this for a generic vector of `double` is not going to be true.  An easy example would be to add a value of about 1E20 and another value of -1E20 or so to the example vector.  Adding any of the `0.5` to either does nothing; when they are added to each other, they cancel.  So the result will be anywhere (on an integer or half-integer) between `0` and the `5000003.50000`